# What is the purpose of JavaScript's apply() in this case?

Tags: javascript

I study the following code to log:

```
console.log.apply( console, arguments );
```

What is the purpose of [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) here?

Why not just `console.log("message", arguments)`?

Comment: The old way to say `console.log(...arguments)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `apply()` function calls another function with a given `this` value and `arguments` provided as an array.

The reason for an implicit `func.apply(obj, args)` is to make sure that within `func()`, `this` refers to `obj`.

Answer (score 8):

```
console.log("message", arguments)
```

calls `log` with two arguments, "message" and the array-like object arguments.

```
console.log.apply( console, arguments );
```

calls it with `n` arguments, where `n` is the length of the array-like object arguments.  In other words, arguments is unwrapped into individual arguments.  The context of the method is `console`.  E.g.:

```
function foo(a, b, c)
{
  console.log.apply( console, arguments );
}
foo(1,2,3);
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
console.log(1,2,3);
```

Comment: For compatibility with IE9 `console.log.apply(console, arguments);` may be changed to `Function.prototype.apply.call(console.log, console, arguments);`

Answer (score 0):

I think both answers did not explain *why*. The real shiny use of this way to program.

I did not like the first voted answer. I could not understand it even reading thrice and the second one feels incomplete.

I think the main purpose to write this way is to use it inside a function (or closures).

So, this line only makes sense inside your customized logger: **console.log.apply( console, arguments );**

Probably it was a better approach than write to something like this:

```
function my_worse_way_to_log_dynamic_args ( [several dynamic arguments] )
{
    // loop each argument
    // call console.log for each one
}

function my_better_way_to_log_dynamic_args ( [several dynamic arguments] )
{
    console.log.apply( console, arguments );
}
```