# jQuery Slideshow not working in IE9

Tags: jquery

I have encountered a very strange problem. The jquery slideshow in the below webpage is not working in IE9. It won't even work on reload. However, if i open the developer tools and refresh the page, it will work. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this.

All the code for the gallery is in scripts/gallery.js

Fixed It: It worked again when i removed "console.log()' from the code. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I am not sure how to close this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gallery script has console log statements in it which causes IE to bork if the dev tools aren't opened (IE9). You're also missing a css file ("NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://blacktoyota.foxqa.com.au/css/RegisterWizard.css?v=1.0")

See also [console.log.apply not working in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538972/console-log-apply-not-working-in-ie9) and [Does IE9 support console.log, and is it a real function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function)

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out line 108 of gallery.js

IE doesn't support the console.log function

Comment: IE supports it when the devtool is open