# javascript calling console.log function with variable length

Tags: javascript

i want to call console.log function with variable length argument

```
function debug_anything() {
  var x = arguments;
  var p = 'DEBUG from ' + (new Error).stack.split("\n")[2];
  switch(x.length) {
    case 0: console.log(p); break;
    case 1: console.log(p,x[0]); break;
    case 2: console.log(p,x[0],x[1]); break;
    case 3: console.log(p,x[0],x[1],x[2]); break;
    case 4: console.log(p,x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]); break;
    // so on..
  }
}
```

is there any (shorter) other way, 
note that i do not want this solution
(since other methods from the x object (Argument or array) would be outputted.

```
console.log(p,x);
```

Comment: See my answer over here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14667091

Regards, Hans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function debug_anything() {
  var x = arguments;
  var p = 'DEBUG from ' + (new Error).stack.split("\n")[2];
    console.log.apply(console, [p].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(x)));
}
```

Comment: +1 I like your code style, do the same as my one, but is stylish!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use `apply`

```
console.log.apply(console, /* your array here */);
```

The full code:

```
function debug_anything() {
  // convert arguments to array
  var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

  var p = 'DEBUG from ' + (new Error).stack.split("\n")[2];

  // Add p to the beggin of x
  x.unshift(p);
  // do the apply magic again
  console.log.apply(console, x);
}
```

Comment: ERROR! Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type

Comment: @Kiswono Prayogo: because of `.call`, not `.apply`. And `console`, not `this`

Comment: @KiswonoPrayogo I do a better example to fix it.

Comment: @KiswonoPrayogo sorry, but for log works was needed to pass `console` as it context. It will work now, you don't need to convert arguments to array if you want, but if you are using a array is better that must be an array hehe

Answer (score 1):

Just `join` the array

```
function debug_anything() {
  var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  var p = 'DEBUG from ' + (new Error).stack.split("\n")[2];

  console.log(p, x.join(', '));
}
```

Comment: ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'join'