# Why does this fail: `function log(){console.log.apply(null,arguments);}`

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap console.log to make it shorter:

```
function log(){console.log.apply(null,arguments);}
```

Why does this usage fail?

```
// this fails
var a=[1,2,3,4];
log(a);
```

Errors:

- Chrome: "Illegal Invocation"
- IE: fails silently
- FF: TypeError: 'log' called on an object that does not implement interface Console."

Comment: Yes, it depends where you run it, it works fine in Node. `console` is not JavaScript, it is provided by the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always seen it as:

```
function log(){console.log.apply(console,arguments);}
```

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to include the console as context. I'll give this a try. Thanks! BTW, is `log` a reserved word--see madforstrength's comment in my question?

Comment: Just tried your solution--works fine now! Thank you :)

Comment: Why are you giving it `null` as a context? `console.log` expects `this` to be `console`, so give it `console`.

Comment: @meagar: Yes, that was my error. It now works fine when I feed it `console` instead of `null`.

Comment: @JustAsking `log` is not reserved, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords

Answer (score -1):

@Ehtesh corrected your syntax, alternatively you can use these methods, as `console.log.apply` not works in old versions of IEs ([console.log.apply not working in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538972/console-log-apply-not-working-in-ie9)).

*Method1:*

```
function log(p_sMessage) {
    if(!Debug) { return; }
    else { if(window.console) { console.log(p_sMessage); }}
}
```

*Method 2:*

`var log = Debug && window.console ? window.console.log.bind(window.console) : function() {};`

or

`var log = (Debug && Window.prototype.Console) ? Window.prototype.console.log.bind(Window.prototype.Console) : function () { };`

(Debug flag sets visibility of console messages exclusively)

**N.B.:** *Method 1* works in all browsers (except those do not support console) but does not show the line number from where it was called. *Method 2* shows the line number but not works in older IEs.