# In IE8, apply method doesn't work

Tags: javascript

i am using javascript `ES6` and `babel`.
but i knew that apply  doesn't work 
finally, i found solution

```
var log = Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console);
log.apply(console, ["this", "is", "a", "test"]);
```

at this link 
[console.log.apply not working in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538972/console-log-apply-not-working-in-ie9)

so i replace from

```
const params = [
      level,
    ].concat(...args)
```

to

```
var params = [ level,]
var concat = Function.prototype.bind.call(params.concat, Array);
var paramsConcated =concat.apply(params, args)
```

but it printed out like this.

```
function Array() { ... },  [second arg...], [third arg..]
```

always print function Array() {...} for first argument.

do i have a misstake?

EDIT 1: 
i'm sorry that did not mention about output. i want to make paramsConcated to [level, args[0], args[1], ... , args[n]].

EDIT 2:
after build, params.concat(...args) is replaced with concat.apply(params.args).
so, i should not use 3 dots.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a description of what the code is supposed to do. What is the desired output?

Comment: So you feel that `.apply()` *"doesn't work"* in IE8, but you haven't defined what doesn't work and instead posted what you think is a solution. How about going back to the original problem. The `.apply()` *does* work, but it works according to ES3, which differs from ES5+.

Comment: `Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console)` is exactly the same as `console.log.bind(console)`. `Function.prototype.bind.call(params.concat, Array);`, if you needed it (which you don't), is exactly the same as 'params.concat.bind(Array)`.

Comment: @squint  did you say that i can use apply if i use es3ify plugin?

Comment: @torazaburo you mean that use it like 'paramsConated=params.concat.bind(args)' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are `bind`ing `concat()` to the `Array` object instead of `params`. That's why you're getting `function Array()` in your output.

But what you're doing is unnecessary. `console` is a special case where its methods don't support `.apply()` in older versions of IE. Arrays do not have that problem.

So just do this:

```
var params = [ level,]
var paramsConcated = params.concat.apply(params, args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You binded `Array` as the `this` value. That's what `bind` does.

I don't understand why you tried `bind`. It seems you only need a reference to `[].concat`.

```js
var params = [ 123 ],
    args = [ [1], 2, [3] ],
    concat = Array.prototype.concat;
console.log(concat.apply(params, args)); // [ 123, 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log(params.concat(...args));     // [ 123, 1, 2, 3 ]
```