# what does this usage of apply() means in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

Please, can someone tell me what does `this.init.apply(this, arguments)` do in the code below?

I understand what `apply()` does in general, but in the context of the code below, what is it doing in there?

```
var Class = function() {

    var klass = function() {
        this.init.apply(this, arguments); //I don't really get this bit...
    };

    klass.prototype.init = function(){};

    return klass;
};

var Person = new Class;

//Usage
var someone =  new Person;
```

I see a lot of people using it. I've got an idea of what it does but can't really put my hands on it so I need more light.

I'm going up an extra level in JS, so I wanna know everything about it, not just the simple 'Hello world' level.

Many thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apply() question for javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638450/apply-question-for-javascript)

Comment: Was there something unclear about how the method was described when you googled for it?

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. Yes, I don't understand why `init` is defined twice in the code above. The question I asked was for the context in which `apply()` applied.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is a *member function* of a function object.  Suppose we have:

```
function saySomething(thing, anotherThing) {
    alert(this + " says " + thing + " and " + anotherThing);
}
```

Then we can use:

```
saySomething.apply(document, ["hello", "goodbye"]);
```

This calls the function and supplies the values of the array as arguments to the function.  The first argument species the *context* of the function (or, what `this` equals when the function runs).

You should also be aware that `arguments` is a special variable that holds an array of all arguments passed to the function.  So, here, `this.init.apply(this, arguments)` means that the `init` function is called and passed all the of arguments that were passed to the `klass` constructor.

In a real implementation, I think `init` would expect arguments.  Consider how this would be done without `apply`:

```
var klass = function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    init(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

klass.prototype.init = function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {}
```

If you wanted to add `arg4` to init, you'd have add it in three places!  By having `klass` transparently pass all its arguments to `init`, you make you code much less brittle.

Comment: Many thanks @apsillers. But why is it calling `init()` inside itself? Why not just use `klass.prototype.init()`? Sorry for bugging you about this, I like to be clear on things...

Comment: It's designed to make `klass` completely transparent -- although `klass` is what gets called when building a new instance, `init` is the function does the real "heavy lifting" and it may expect arguments.  To save you the trouble of duplicating an argument list on `klass` and `init`, `klass` takes no named arguments and simply passes all arguments to `init` by using `apply` and `arguments`.  Why was it done this way?  I don't know enought about the Klass library to say.

Comment: Edited for further clarification.

Comment: Now I get it, thank you very much. That's the explanation I wanted to clear things.... But instead of this technique, could an object been used as an argument? As in key/value properties as arguments... i.e. `{key1: value1, key2: value2,...keyN: valueN}`...

Comment: Sure, that's a perfectly valid and not uncommon pattern, and you could have use it instead of (or in conjunction with) the apply/arguments pattern.